# Closure that takes a generic type?

Tags: swift, closures

With the following completion handler code, why is it giving me an error about the type of `completionClosure`?

```
enum ModelSerializerError: Error {
    case readjson(String)
    case writejson(String)
    case writeFirebase(String)
    case readFirebase(String)
}

enum ModelSerializerResult<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(ModelSerializerError)
}

static func serializeToFirebase<T>(value: T.Type, path: String, completion: @escaping (ModelSerializerResult<Void>) -> Void) where T: Encodable { ... }

// Later in some function...

let handleError : (Error) -> () =
    { error in
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

let completionClosure : (ModelSerializerResult) -> () =
    { result in // Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to specified type '(ModelSerializerResult) -> ()'
        switch result {
        case .success(let val): ()
        case .failure(let error): handleError(error)
        }
    }

serializeToFirebase(value: MyClass.self, path: path, completion: completionClosure)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit tricky if you're new to closure syntax. In this example, I'm missing the generic. Change the line:

```
let completionClosure : (ModelSerializerResult) -> () =
```

to

```
let completionClosure : (ModelSerializerResult<Void>) -> () =
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the closure syntax, it's about knowing generic types and knowing that there is no such type `ModelSerializerResult`, there are only concrete specialisations of it when you want to use it as a variable type. You'd get the same error is you wanted to type annotate a simple generic variable without making it a closure.

Comment: Sure, but this is a common use case for running into this error. A developer who does not know they are messing up the generic aspect will search for something along these lines. Can't search for what you don't know.